# Upgrade AzureRM Powershell on Hosted 2017 Agent (VSTS - Visual Studio Team Services)

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I am using release management through Visual Studio Teams Services (online). We use Hosted build Agents and I really want to avoid the overhead of managing custom agents.

One item I do need is the AzureRM PowerShell module. Versions up to 5.1.1 are [available on the agent](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md) but I need 6.0.0.

What I would like to do is use a step in my release process (PowerShell) to aquire version 6.0.0 and use thart instead, however I cant quite get it to work. I have tried a few approaches that have all come unstuck, the current one is:

```
Write-Output "------------------ Install package provider ------------------"
Find-PackageProvider -Name "NuGet" | Install-PackageProvider -Scope CurrentUser -Force

Write-Output "------------------ Remove Modules ------------------"
Get-Module -ListAvailable | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'AzureRM*'} | Remove-Module

Write-Output "------------------ Install the AzureRM version we want - 6.0.1!  ------------------"
Install-Package AzureRM -RequiredVersion 6.0.1 -Scope CurrentUser -Force

Write-Output "------------------ Import AzureRM 6.0.1  ------------------"
Import-Module AzureRM -RequiredVersion 6.0.1
```

This all works fine (i.e. does not crash...) but then when I try and use one of the 6.0.1 cmdlets I get an error.

> Get-AzureRmADGroup : The Azure PowerShell session has not been
>   properly initialized.  Please import the module and try again.

Any idea of where I am going wrong or alternate strategies I can use to deploy AzureRM 6.0.1 and use it on a hosted agent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figured it out - adding an answer for anyone else that suffers the same.

The key is to login after the AzureRM module is upgraded.

**PowerShell code:**

```
    Write-Output "------------------ Start: Upgrade AzureRM on build host ------------------"

    Write-Output "- - - - - Install package provider"
    Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force -Scope CurrentUser

    Write-Output "- - - - - List Modules Before"
    Get-Module -ListAvailable| where {$_.Name -Like “*AzureRM*”}  | Select Name, Version

    Write-Output "- - - - - Remove alll existing AzureRM Modules" 
    Get-Module -ListAvailable | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*AzureRM*'} | Remove-Module -Force 

    Write-Output "- - - - - Install AzureRM 6.0.1"
    Install-Module -Name AzureRM -RequiredVersion 6.0.1 -Force -Scope CurrentUser

    Write-Output "- - - - - Import AzureRM 6.0.1"
    Import-Module AzureRM -Force -Verbose -Scope Local

    Write-Output "- - - - - List Modules After"
    Get-Module -ListAvailable| where {$_.Name -Like “*AzureRM*”}  | Select Name, Version

    Write-Output "------------------ End: Upgrade AzureRM on build host ------------------"

    Write-Output "------------------ Start: LoginToAzure ------------------"

    $SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $AdminPassword -AsPlainText -Force
    $AdminCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($AdminUserEmailAddress, $SecurePassword)
    Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $AdminCredential

    Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId | Select-AzureRmSubscription

    Write-Output "------------------ End: LoginToAzure ------------------"
```

Comment: Hi, following along I get  
`The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Error in TypeData "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.IAzureContextContainer": The TypeConverter was ignored because it already occurs`. I suspect due to an older version of AzureRm.Profile being loaded and unable to unload it https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/preview/documentation/troubleshoot-module-load.md#symptom-error-when-importing-an-azure-powershell-module how did you get around that please? Was there any other task settings you needed to do?

Comment: Oh, unless perhaps I should be using the plain PowerShell and not Azure Powershell task... I've just started another line of thoughts in my head :-)

Comment: I am using the plain PowerShell with a deployment account. I found the Azure PowerShell too restrictive.

Comment: Ah ha, thanks Murray I just came to the same conclusion as I got some fresh air yesterday! :-)

Comment: I really wanted the Azure PowerShell to work so that a service principal could be used, but alas gave up in the end. Now with full PowerShell I can control everything and deploy my ARM Templates too.

Comment: Yeah I really wanted that service principal too, I have some good news I began to reverse engineer the PowerShell Azure VSTS task along with the vsts-image to understand how it's dependency management worked and I _think_ I have a nice solution, I'll post as a separate answer once I've done a bit more testing.

Comment: Cool, that would be handy and save me some pain too :)

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to Murray for the initial point in the right direction, to show what I was hoping to do wasn't impossible!

I initially tried to do this within the Azure PowerShell task and got pretty far but hit a dead end with AzureRm.Profile [as you cannot unload an old version](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/preview/documentation/troubleshoot-module-load.md#why-are-incompatibilities-possible).

The trick was to understanding how the AzureRM VSTS task does it's dependency setup, it effectively takes the "Azure Powershell Version" string in the VSTS UI and uses it to define an additional search path in the PSModules environmental variable i.e. `C:\Modules\azurerm_5.1.1`.

It will look in that directory, before searching the user profile, then the global modules path.

As soon as it finds the module it performs the Azure login, which will hamper any hope of removing the module after.

So if you instead use a plain powershell task i.e. one that AzureRM isn't loaded into (as Murray also concluded):

[image: Plain Powershell Task]

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force -Scope CurrentUser
Install-Module -Name AzureRM -RequiredVersion 6.2.1 -Force -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber
```

Notably install-module won't be installing to c:\modules like the [vsts image generation project](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation).

I seemed to need AllowClobber to get around problems overriding old powershell versions when experimenting, but I suspect I don't need that anymore.

The elegant solution kicks in when next using the Azure PowerShell script.

[image: Azure PowerShell Task]

The preferred powershell version field filled in with 6.2.1 will add `C:\Modules\azurerm_6.2.1` to the PSModules path. This doesn't exist, but thankfully because PSModules still includes the user specific modules path, so our 6.2.1 is loaded by itself!

Luckily the AzureRM.Profile from 5.1.1 is forwards compatible enough that the service principal login performed by the Azure Powershell task still works.

Running

```
Get-Module AzureRm 
Get-AzureRmContext
```

Will output the versions you are hoping for:

[image: VSTS azure rm powershell versions]

Notably if it weren't able to login, I *think* System.AccessToken could be used (if the option is switched on in the agent phase level).

**Diagnostic Techniques if the workaround needs tweaking:**

Things that helped greatly, reading through the code that loads in AzureRM in the task:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzurePowerShellV3/AzurePowerShell.ps1#L80

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/0703b8869041d64db994934bde97de167787ed2e/Tasks/Common/VstsAzureHelpers_/ImportFunctions.ps1

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzurePowerShellV3/Utility.ps1#L18

And also how the VSTS image is generated:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/blob/2f57db26dc30ae0f257a3415d26eaa8eea0febf9/images/win/scripts/Installers/Install-AzureModules.ps1

Enabing System.Debug = true as a environment release variable.
Then using [VSCode's Log File Highlighter plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emilast.LogFileHighlighter)

---

**I'd encourage anyone who's interested to vote** in: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/issues/149

As the AzureRM version at the time of writing is waaaay out of date on the VSTS Hosted 2017 agent.

Unfortunately I can't submit a PR to upgrade it, as it's pulled in via a zip file hosted privately.

Comment: That's kind of you @Murray! Catch you offline :-)

Comment: You wouldn't believe how many releases and crazy code it took to reach this option!

Comment: Please note for people reading this now, AzureRM is now already upgraded to the version I was trying to upgrade to. But this information might still be useful if going to a higher version perhaps.