# Azure DevOps (VSTS) - using Azure Az PowerShell on a Hosted Agent

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli, az

We use Azure DevOps with a hosted VS2017 build agent. We would like to use the the new [Az PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az/). However, the [VS2017 hosted build agent](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md) has AzureRM installed on it. The documentation states [You should not install Az side-by-side with AzureRM. Remove all AzureRM modules before installing Az.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/azure-powershell-cross-platform-az-module-replacing-azurerm/) and this indeed is necessary because the two conflict. There is also no Az PowerShell build task.

So the question is, how do I use the Azure Az PowerShell module from an Azure DevOps hosted VS2017 build agent?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the answer is - you dont (for the time being). <strike>Because you wont have permissions to remove the azure powershell module</strike>. Ok, apparently you can do that.

Another way to make it work, use a docker container as a build agent (inside hosted agent). That can have Az module, obviously.

Comment: Docker is an interesting idea. You can remove AzureRM, you just uninstall it from the session and then install Az but I am hoping for a slicker solution so will hold out for more / better answers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375331/upgrade-azurerm-powershell-on-hosted-2017-agent-vsts-visual-studio-team-servi

Comment: you can always use your own agent. I'd personally not go the way of uninstalling azure.powershell from the agent. another thing you can do - use something like ACI or Azure Function and call those, they will have Az module and just execute your code

Comment: I really don't want to secure, operate and manage my own agents. Uninstalling works better than you would expect. Functions is another good idea.

Answer (score 0):

They cannot be installed side by side, however one can be installed in PowerShell (non core), and the other in PowerShell Core.

From the [comments](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/azure-powershell-cross-platform-az-module-replacing-azurerm/) in the docs you specified:

> Question: The document says not to install the modules side-by-side but is there any reason that we cannot run AzureRM in PowerShell 5.1 and AZ in PowerShell Core on the same machine?
>
> Answer: No, no reason at all. In fact we are thinking of suggesting this as an advanced scenario for those with a substantial investment in AzureRM scripts