# AzureRM commands in Azure powershell Task: Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I am trying to run a script in the Azure Powershell Task in Azure DevOps that uses AzureRM commands. I tried to use Task version `4.*` and `5.*`. Both of them are giving error saying that the AzureRM commands couldnt be recognized. (eg. `Get-AzureRmResourceGroup` is not recognized). What should I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have there Az Modules available not AzureRM so if you try this

```yaml
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'rg-the-code-manual'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: 'Get-AzResourceGroup -Name "TheCodeManual"'
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

You should get your result.

And if you want you may try to uninstall Az modules and then install AzureRm module. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/uninstall-az-ps?view=azps-4.6.1) you have example how to uninstall az modules.

Here is a simple solution:
[image]

You may also take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375331/upgrade-azurerm-powershell-on-hosted-2017-agent-vsts-visual-studio-team-servi) to see how to force installation.